# Windows command line: find files by text string and open them

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying create a batch file in Win2K8 to grep (note use of non-Windows term in Windows context) a set of directories for files containing a certain string, and want to then open the resulting files so that I can review them manually.

So far, I'm able to list the files I want fairly easily (`findstr /S /M searchString *.txt`), but I can't figure out how to pipe that to `start` or any other Windows command to open the file. I've also used vanilla `find`, but wasn't able to get that working either.

I have to do this for a lot of different strings, hence the scripting approach. For what it's worth, I'm open to suggestions using PowerShell if there's a good method there I don't know about (and I don't know much PowerShell; I'll be exploring it in the meantime), but can't install any other tools on the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FOR` command to process your list. In a .CMD file, do something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F %%i IN ('findstr /S /M seachString *.txt') DO (
  ECHO %%i
  REM Do something with %%i here
)
```

Comment: I always forget the Windows command doesn't work at all like I expect.